# Unable to click tree plus icon in Search using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm unable to click the plus icon in the tree view and checked the HTML snippet, it shows id,title and class but its highlighted entire row so i'm unable to identify the plus icon. I googled more than a week, no solution found. Please assist me on this. Attached the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here would be to *click with offset*. Example in Java:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action actions = builder.moveToElement(element, 25, 0).click().build();
actions.perform();
```

where 25 and 0 in this case, basically, mean the `x` and `y` offsets starting from the top left corner of the element where the mouse would be moved and the click would be performed.

Comment: Hi Alecxe, i got x=254 and y=380 for one webelement using Point .  WebElement tree = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dynamic-tree-branch dynamic-tree-trunk']/li[contains(@title,'Genetic modulator')]"));
 
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 Action actions = builder.moveToElement(tree, 254, 0).click().build();
 actions.perform(); It doesnt work so what exact value i need to give for x and y offset.

Comment: @Vadivelan I don't know which values to put for x and y since the example you've provided is not reproducible.

Comment: yes Alecxe. i need to click left corner of webelement so x and y values are negative or positive.Please confirm

Comment: @Vadivelan how about you try with 0, 0? (top left corner)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend xpath for this (unless you expect the site to change drastically)

the xpath selector you could use may look something like

```
  //*[@id="ID_OF_TARGET_ELEMENT"]
```

Comment: if you see html snippet, id value common for both plus and text so i couldnt able to identify the locator for plus icon.